# redux-form, validation breaks if using returned function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux-form

I'm using redux form and want to do custom validation messages.

I used their example validation project here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/PNQYw1kVy

As is, it works as expected. If I change the validation function for a required field from

`const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required'`

to

`const required = message => value => value ? undefined : message || 'Required'`

and change the validation definition for the name and email from

`validate={[ required ]}`

to

`validate={[ required('Message') ]}` or `validate={[ required(null) ]}`

then it doesn't process the validation.

Why does this happen? To my understanding if we have `const myFunc = val => val` and `const myFunc2 = () => val => val` then `[myFunc, myFunc2()]` would result in an array of 2 functionally identical functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use validation function wrapped into another function, every time the form is rendered it will construct a new function, which will cause field to rerender  (because `this.props.validate !== nextProps.validate`).(check this [issue on github](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2453))

You can use specifically defined instances of parameterized validation rules:

```
const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required';
const requiredMessage = required('Message');

<Field
    name="username"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    validate={requiredMessage}
/>
```

Also, this is the reason why validation functions that is defined in form component doesn't work.

```
const FormComponent = (props) => {
    const {handleSubmit, submitting} = props;
    const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required'; //this will not work!!!

    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
            name='username'
            type='text'
            component={renderField}
            label='Username'
            validate={required}
        />
        <div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! :D This makes a lot of sense